# NullReferenceException even after checking with IsDBNull

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following code:

```
Dim getProspect = (From p In dbContext.IRF_Prospects _
                   Where p.url = prospect_url _
                   Select p).FirstOrDefault
' If they have a record...
If Not IsDBNull(getProspect) Then
    If IsDBNull(getProspect.user_id) Then
        ' Prepopulate the form with their information.
        txtFirst.Text = getProspect.first_name
Else
        ' Redirect them to login.
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
End If
```

When I execute it, it throws an object reference not set to an instance of an object error on `getProspect.user_id`. Why is it doing this? Shouldn't the fact that I'm verifying it exists using `IsDBNull` first keep this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DBNull` is not the same as `Nothing`, and what you have is `Nothing`. `FirstOrDefault`, as the name suggests, returns the first item or the default value, which is `Nothing` for reference types - never `DBNull`.

```
Dim getProspect = (From p In dbContext.IRF_Prospects _
                   Where p.url = prospect_url _
                   Select p).FirstOrDefault
' If they have a record...
If getProspect IsNot Nothing Then
    If IsDBNull(getProspect.user_id) Then
        ' Prepopulate the form with their information.
        txtFirst.Text = getProspect.first_name
    Else
        ' Redirect them to login.
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
    End If
```