# Null Reference in datagridview with "Not IsDBNull"

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dbnull

IN VB.net 2012 this is my code:

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridViewAddPlanning.Rows
        If Not IsDBNull(row.Cells(0).Value) Then

            Dim sqlcmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand = New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
            sqlcmd.Connection = sqlConn
            sqlcmd.CommandText = sqlQuery

            sqlcmd.Connection = sqlConn
            sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            sqlcmd.CommandText = sqlQuery
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = LabelUserName.Text
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@ActiveDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Now.ToShortDateString
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@Cat", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "User's Planning"
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@Task", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = row.Cells(0).Value.ToString
            sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@DateStarted", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Now.ToShortDateString

            Try
                sqlConn.Open()
                sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As SqlException
                MessageBox.Show("The task from line " & row.Index.ToString & " could not be added. Error Message:", ex.Message.ToString())
            End Try

        End If
    Next
```

I get the error: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred"
at the second line. I cant see the reason for this.. Any Ideas?

Comment: Sorry, just saw in a previous post it should be Isnothing. Just replaced IsDBNull with IsNothing and it worked :-)

Comment: You wrote your comment 1 minute after I wrote my answer saying exactly the same. Perhaps it was pure coincidence but, just in case, don't expect any more help from me.

Comment: Your comment did not show when i posted mine, sorry if i wasted your time. Thanks for helping anyway

Comment: No, I didn't mean my comment. I wrote an answer before you wrote you comment. Look at it now... I will undelete it for a while for you see it (again). As you can see, it was written 1 hour ago (like your comment; but one minute before it). As said... perhaps was a coincidence (although you should have posted the link you are referring), but just in case, I will better not help you further until making sure that all this was a coincidence :) Enjoy the view, because I will delete it again in a (short) while.

Comment: I guess i refreshed the page just too early, because the answer was not there when i commented. Your answer does provide more insight as to why i got the error, so thanks. This is the link were i got the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711386/nullreferenceexception-even-after-checking-with-isdbnull

Comment: Thanks. This is all what I needed. See? Best thing to avoid misunderstandings is just being clear. This link provides a more solid base for your statement (for future readers) and avoids problems (like the one with me).

Comment: PS: I have deleted my answer anyway because this is not a too-difficult-to-understand matter and the provided link is clear enough. I only cared because of understanding some bad faith, if it was just a misunderstanding, I don't deserve the award because of  replying something you already knew (and awards are discretional). I only care about good/bad faith, rep/awards are not too important.